# How to pass file object through ajax sumbit with spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am trying to pass the file object through jquery ajax submit.

**JSP code**

```
<div id="import-file">
        <input type="file" id="file"/>
        <table>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="type" value="csv"></td><td>CSV File</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="type" value="excel"></td><td>Excel spread sheet</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="type" value="tab"></td><td>Tab delimited</td></tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

**Java script code**

```
        var type = $($('input:radio:checked')[0]).val();
        var file = $("#file")[0].files[0];
        alert($("#file")[0].files[0].name);
        $.ajax({
            data :{
                "file" : file,
                "type" : type
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "fileupload.htm",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert(err);
            }
        });
```

finally here is my spring controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="fileupload.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST )
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(@RequestParam String type, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        logger.info("file type : "+type + "file is "+file.toString());
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

Am getting NS_NOINTERFACE: Component does not have requested interface [nsIDOMBlob.slice] error in my firebug console.

Comment: You have to pass formData

Comment: data is formData only right

Comment: Now you're passing the files object, and that won't work, you need to pass the file itself, and that has to be passed as [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: can  you correct the above code and post it as an answer it will be helpful to me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: getting this error TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42982/discussion-between-ramesh-k-and-adeneo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved it like this:

**JavaScript code**

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);    
    console.log("form data "+formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fileupload.htm',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

**JSP Code**

```
<form action="fileupload.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fileinfo">
<input type="file" name="fileName" id="file"/>
</form>
```

**Spring Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="fileupload.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST )
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(@RequestParam("fileName") MultipartFile file){
        try{
            logger.info("file is "+file.toString());

        }catch(Exception e){
            return "error occured "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps some body.